# Delphi and Firebase Push Notifications

Tags: delphi, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Rad Studio Berlin Update 2 and got Google Firebase with push notifications working with Android, but iOS seems to be blocking my ability to come up with a DeviceToken request.  I'm wondering how others have solved the problem.

I'm using the following in the FormCreate event

```
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
PushService := TPushServiceManager.Instance.GetServiceByName(TPushService.TServiceNames.GCM);
PushService.AppProps[TPushService.TAppPropNames.GCMAppID] := '579735395957';
{$ELSE}
PushService := TPushServiceManager.Instance.GetServiceByName(TPushService.TServiceNames.APS);
{$ENDIF}

ServiceConnection := TPushServiceConnection.Create(PushService);
ServiceConnection.Active := True;
ServiceConnection.OnChange := OnServiceConnectionChange;
ServiceConnection.OnReceiveNotification := OnReceiveNotificationEvent;
```

I get a dialog popup on ios that prevent me from getting the DeviceToken as shown below

```
DeviceId := PushService.DeviceIDValue[TPushService.TDeviceIDNames.DeviceId];
DeviceToken := PushService.DeviceTokenValue[TPushService.TDeviceTokenNames.DeviceToken];
```

but all this works fine on Android.  Thoughts anyone?

Comment: What message is shown in the dialog popup on iOS?

Comment: The "XXXX would like to send you notifications" dialog box appears as soon as the app launches.  So anything I seem to put in Form.Create or Form.Activate with regards to the above code gets blocked.  But if I use the above from a user initiated button event or something that works fine.

Comment: @zack this message should be expected. It is iOS behavior. iOS informs user about permissions your app is going to access and prompts user about granting them, or not.